# What does it mean that the bridge is no longer damped?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I get stuck in an ODE exercise. I have only studied Physics in secondary school, so I have a hard time understanding the question:

Oscillations on a foot bridge can be modeled by the following ODE:

$$M x'' + k x' + h x = 300 N x'$$

where $M, k, h \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Physically, $M$ is the mass and $N$ is the number of pedestrians walking on the bridge.

Our goal is to express $N_0 = \min \{N_1 \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{the bridge is no longer damped if $N > N_1$}\}$ as a function of $k, h, M$.

What is meant by $``\text{the bridge is no longer damped}''$? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the amplitude  of the solution diverges at the increasing of time.

So, recast first the equation in canonical form
$$
\eqalign{
  & Mx'' + kx' + hx = 300Nx'  \cr 
  & Mx'' + \left( {k - 300N} \right)x' + hx = 0  \cr 
  & x'' + \left( {{{k - 300N} \over M}} \right)x' + {h \over M}x = 0 \cr} 
$$
which is a 2nd order linear ODE.

Then you (presumably) know that the solution to the linear ODE
$$
x'' + a\,x' + b\,x = 0
$$
is
$$
\eqalign{
  & x(t) = c_{\,1} \,e^{ - \,a/2\,t} \,e^{\left( {\sqrt {a^{\,2}  - 4b} } \right)/2\;t}  + c_{\,2} \,e^{ - \,a/2\,t} \,e^{ - \,\left( {\sqrt {a^{\,2}  - 4b} } \right)/2\;t}  =   \cr 
  &  = e^{ - \,a/2\,t} \left( {c_{\,1} \,\,e^{\left( {\sqrt {a^{\,2}  - 4b} } \right)/2\;t}  + c_{\,2} \,e^{ - \,\left( {\sqrt {a^{\,2}  - 4b} } \right)/2\;t} } \right) \cr} 
$$

The evolution in time of the amplitude of the signal is governed by 
$$
e^{ - \,a/2\,t}
$$
irrespective of whether the square root provides real or imaginary values, because:

- if real, you have in any case that $\sqrt {a^{\,2}  - 4b}  < a$ if $0<b$
- if imaginary, the term in brackets translates into a sinusoidal signal of constant amlitude

So the amplitude of the resulting signal *will damp out in time* if $0<a$ and $0<b$.

In our case 
$$
a = {{k - 300N} \over M}
$$
and $h$ and $M$ and thus $b$ are positive, for physical considerations.

Finally we get that the system  becomes *unstable = no longer damped* if
$$
a \le 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad {{k - 300N} \over M}\le 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad {k \over {300}} \le N\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\lceil {{k \over {300}}} \right\rceil  \le N
$$

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra: I was assuming that the OP knew about ODE solution, and was just asking the meaning of "not-damped". However I accept your critics, and extended my answer.